# Random generator in python

Tags: python-3.x, random

I want to select one of 0 or 1 based on some probability of getting 1 and some initial seed.

I tried following:

```
import random

population = [0,1]
random.seed(33)
probabilities = [0.4,0.2,0.5]

def sampleIt():
    selectedProb = random.randrange(0,3,1) #select one of probabilities
    print('Selected Probability: ', selectedProb)
    return random.choices(population, [0, probabilities[selectedProb-1]])

for i in range(100):
    sample = sampleIt()
    print(sample[0])
```

Below is sample output:

```
Selected Probability:  0.2
1
Selected Probability:  0.5
1
Selected Probability:  0.4
1
Selected Probability:  0.2
1
Selected Probability:  0.5
1
Selected Probability:  0.2
1
```

Doubts:

1. As you can see, it is able to randomly select probabilities. But for each selected probability, it ends up selecting 1 from population. If it selected probability 0.2, then I expect it to select 1 with probability 0.2. In this way, it should have selected 0 at least once. But that is not happening. Why is this so?
2. Is `seed` correct set or we have to set differently?
3. Also, what changes I need to do if I expect `sampleIt()` to be called from different threads?
4. Also is there any standard practice to improve performance, say if I run this millions of time? Do I have to use numpy for random number generation?
5. Does `random.randrange()` and `random.choice()` follow uniform distribution?

You can run code online [here](https://repl.it/@RanjanMaria/TrustworthyVictoriousMedia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several critical errors here.  Let's talk about that and then the correct way to do this.

First, if this were working properly, you'd be getting 1 with net probability of 0.37, which is 1/3*(0.2 + 0.4 + 0.5) because you are randomly choosing a probability.

You are passing weights to `random.choices` in the second positional argument, and you are passing a weight of 0 for option zero, so it will never be picked.  In that same statement, you are unnecessarily subtracting 1 from the range that you have...

So, to do this properly for Bernoulli trials, you can just draw a random number and compare it to the probability you want.  Or you can use `random.choices` correctly and get a list.

```
In [14]: def gen_sample(p_success): 
    ...:     if random.random() < p_success: 
    ...:         return 1 
    ...:     return 0 
    ...:                                                                        

In [15]: gen_sample(0.95)                                                       
Out[15]: 1

In [16]: gen_sample(0.02)                                                       
Out[16]: 0

In [17]: p_success = 0.85                                                       

In [18]: random.choices([0, 1], weights=[1-p_success, p_success], k=10)         
Out[18]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: great to the point...ahh I made mistake with `weights` and super thanks for the another approach

Comment: any comment on what will be more efficient? `if` approach or `choices` approach?

Comment: One more doubt. Say I want to generate random numbers for different purposes. Say one for task1, another for task2 and yet another for task3. Should I create three different instances of `random.Random()`, for having proper uniform distribution within those tasks? (I may need to generate from from different ranges for these three tasks, say task1 requires random number out of `[0,1]`, task2 out of `[0,1,2,3,4]` and task3 out of `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`).

Comment: regarding if/choices...it depends on how you plan to consume the numbers.  Whatever makes sense.  You do not need multiple instances of random.  Just use one and formulate the `choices` command properly for each need.